# Laravel Change URL First page Routes

Tags: laravel-5

I have an Laravel 5.4 Website with User Login.
If i enter the Url the script redirect to Login page, not "home" of course.

I want now an new Page if i enter the URL not Login Page. An Page with Login Button and after it goes to Login page. I have created an new blade where i want as first page: `start.blade.php`

How i can change this?

I have try it with my code in web.php but dont work, my Code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function(){
  Route::get('logout','AuthController@Logout')->name('logout');
  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
  Route::get('myprofile','ProfileController@Index')->name('profile');
```

Comment: You want to be redirected to the new page ??

Comment: Yes correct. I want force the script to open the "start.blade.php" before the login, as first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a new route for your page outside the group :

```
Route::get('start','tController@start')->name('start');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function(){
  Route::get('logout','AuthController@Logout')->name('logout');
  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
  Route::get('myprofile','ProfileController@Index')->name('profile');
}
```

And then you have to change in the `Exceptions->Handler.php` :

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login')); // <-- change here :)
}
```

You have to change `return redirect()->guest(route('login'));` to your new route :)

```
return redirect()->guest(route('start'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new `route` in your `routes.php` file with no middleware attached to it. Use this:-

> Route::get('start','StartController@start')->name('start');

Now your `routes.php` file should looks like this :-

```
// Newly added route for handling pre-login calls.
Route::get('start','StartController@start')->name('start');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function(){
  Route::get('logout','AuthController@Logout')->name('logout');
  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
  Route::get('myprofile','ProfileController@Index')->name('profile');
});
```

You need to create a new controller `StartController` with a function named `start` to achieve this without disturbing current structure of code.

start function in controller:-

```
public function start() {
 return view('< new view name here >');
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats already added , but how can i force the script to open the "start" page before login/home ?

Comment: You can directly open view from route file as well - Route::get('/paths/{$path}, function($path){
   return view('paths/{$path}/index);
}); e

Comment: Dont i rewrite the Login page with it and cant use it again after it?

Comment: Can you please further explain your comment ?